# Table cell swipe menu using SWTableViewCell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm implementing the Table Swipe menu using the component [SWTableViewCell](https://components.xamarin.com/view/swtableviewcell), in VisualStudio (Xamario.iOS). Below is my code for the method "GetCell"

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)`<br/>
{
    SWTableViewCell.SWTableViewCell cell = null;
    cell =  (SWTableViewCell.SWTableViewCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);

    if (cell == null)
        cell = new SWTableViewCell.SWTableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);

    cell.SetRightUtilityButtons(GetButtons(), 30.5f);
    cell.Delegate = new SWTableViewCell.SWTableViewCellDelegate();

    cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row];
}


private UIButton[] GetButtons()
{
    UIButton[] buttons = new UIButton[1];

    UIButton btn = new UIButton();
    btn.SetTitle("Delete", UIControlState.Normal);

    buttons[0] = btn;
    UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("Profile/Images/house");
    btn.SetImage(image, UIControlState.Normal);

    return buttons;
}
```

I do not get any exception in these methods but after all these I'm getting the exception at the line UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate") in Main method.

`NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil`

If I skip the line "SetRightUtilityButtons", I'm getting all the rows without any problem. But I would like to have slider kind of menu.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. How did you get it resolved? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what I did. But I can fix yours if you can share your code.

Answer (score 3):

Having ran into the same error message as above, I dug into the exception call stack and found that the color of the button needs to be set explicitly. The helper code from [the original project on github](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell/blob/023138f2c2427982f4c5e184ff9add1d1dd8ecf8/SWTableViewCell/PodFiles/NSMutableArray%2BSWUtilityButtons.m) has several methods that help create buttons. I translated the `sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor` function and it now works perfectly.

I'm also using [MVVMCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) so I added the following helper method to a subclass of `SWTableViewCell` as follows:

```
public class MvxSwTableViewCell
    : SWTableViewCell, IMvxBindable
{

    // Rest of class omitted

    public static UIButton GetUtilityButtonWithColor(UIColor color, string title)
    {
        var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
        button.BackgroundColor = color;
        button.SetTitle(title, UIControlState.Normal);
        button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
        button.TitleLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

        return button;
    }
}
```

I now use this to create my utility buttons in the `GetOrCreateCellFor` method in my `MvxTableViewSource`.

Hope that helps anyone else that runs into this. And a big thank you to [Nagaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381970/nagaraj) for offering to help, if I hadn't worked this out I would've taken up your offer!

Answer (score 0):

I have done using SWTableViewCell in Xamarin.iOS with Mvvmcross DataConsumer:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Views;
using SWTableViewCells;
using UIKit;

namespace SubViews
{
    public partial class SampleTableViewCell : SWTableViewCell, IMvxBindable
    {
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("SampleTableViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }

    public object DataContext 
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }

    static SampleTableViewCell ()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName ("SampleTableViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    public static SampleTableViewCell Create ()
    {
        return (SampleTableViewCell)Nib.Instantiate (null, null) [0];
    }

    public SampleTableViewCell (string bindingText, IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        this.CreateBindingContext (bindingText);
    }

    protected SampleTableViewCell (IntPtr handle) : this (string.Empty, handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind (() => {
            var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<SampleTableViewCell, Type> ();
            //Custom Bindings
            bindings.Apply ();
        });
    }
}
```